# How to create a prototype method that uses closure to save different values while still points to the same memory?

Tags: javascript

I am learning prototypal inheritance in Javascript, and I want to create prototype method that would use closures to same some data instead of accepting all of them as parameters.

Using `map()` of `Array.prototype.map()` as an example:

```js
const arr = new Array(1, 2)
const arr1 = new Array(1, 3)

console.log(arr.map === arr1.map) //true, pointing to the same memory
console.log(arr.map.toString()) //function map() { [native code] }
console.log(arr.map(x => x + 1)) //[ 2, 3 ], giving the correct result
console.log(arr1.map(x => x + 2)) //[ 3, 5 ]
```

But for my own implementation, I have to make **a new function to save the value of that instance**. Is it possible to make it **points to the same place in memory while keeping the value encapsulated in closure different**? Is it possible for `map()` because it is written in native code?

My implmentation:

```js
    function MyArray(...value){
      this.value = new Array(value)
      this.map = (fn) => MyArray.prototype.map(value, fn)
    }

    MyArray.prototype.map = (value, fn) => value //Pretends that I have handle the map() logic here...

    const arr = new MyArray(1, 2)
    const arr1 = new MyArray(1, 3) 

    console.log(arr.map === arr1.map) //false, pointing to different memory
    console.log(arr.map(x => x)) //[ 1, 2 ]
    console.log(arr1.map(x => x)) //[ 1, 3 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning a value to the `map` property of the instance in your `MyArray` constructor. Every time the constructor runs to construct a new instance, a newly created function gets assigned to the `map` property.

Just remove the `this.map` assignment inside the constructor entirely.

```js
function MyArray(...value) {
  this.value = new Array(value)
}

MyArray.prototype.map = function(callback) {
  return this.value.map(callback);
}

const arr = new MyArray(1, 2)
const arr1 = new MyArray(1, 3)

console.log(arr.map === arr1.map)
console.log(arr.map(x => x)) //[ 1, 2 ]
console.log(arr1.map(x => x)) //[ 1, 3 ]
```

Comment: Didn't realize I can use `this` inside prototype method as well. Thank you and I will mark your answer as correct.